# return is not working in ajax result

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

The return is not working in this code -

```html
public function articleImage_1_Refresh(){
    $article_id = trim(Input::get('article_id'));
    $article_id = Crypt::decrypt($article_id);
    $singleData = DB::table('articles')
        ->where('id',$article_id)
        ->get();
    $image_1 = $singleData[0]->image_1;
    //return $image_1;
    return '<img id="article_image_1" class="img-responsive custom_margin_auto" src="{{URL::asset('images/articles/'.$image_1)}}" alt="Article Image 1"></img>';
}
```

Which will be used in -

```js
success:function(result){ // you wrote here response
    alert (result);
    $('#article_image_1_container').html(result);
}
```

There is a syntax error in the return line, but can not figure out.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`success:function(result)` is not correct JavaScript. Try `var success = function(result)`.

Next time, try looking at the console and figure out what exactly throws a syntax error. It's faster than pasting code here :).

Comment: no, this is not working. I forgot to say this is Laravel project.----- my page is showing 2 error - Class App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController does not exist AND Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'images' (T_STRING), expecting ';' ------ when I change the 'return' line by - return '<img id="article_image_1" class="img-responsive custom_margin_auto" src="{{URL::asset('.'images/articles/'.$image_1.')}}" alt="Article Image 1"></img>'; ------ the error in consol shows - 404 (Not Found) - whereas the image is already there.

Comment: I was merely commenting on the wrong JavaScript syntax. It looks like you may have multiple problems - both server and client side. You need to debug this further.